# Import class from a file in an upper directory withing python / django

Tags: python, django

I have a django project and I need to import models into another folder which is in a sub directory which is in the same folder as the file I am trying to import to...

I am trying to import classes from models into profileViews.py This is what I have right now:

`from .models import Profile`

here isthe directory setup

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing modules from parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder)

Comment: I looked at it, but i couldnt really figure out the issue and how to fix it  @KaitoEinstein

Answer (score 0):

You can use either a relative import:

`from ..models import Profile`

Where "Profile is the model class you want.

Or, import absolutely with the app name "splitt":

`from splitt.models import Profile`

Comment: I got the pathing correct after looking at the other article... Thank You